# mongodb, Updating a field in an object in array field equal to a document field

Tags: mongodb

let's say I have docs such as

```
{
  "nickname": "my nickname",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

how do I update it to look like

```
{
  "nickname": "my nickname",
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nickname": "my nickname"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nickname": "my nickname"
    }
  ]
}
```

This does not seem to be working

```
db.getCollection('users').update(
{
    "comments.nickname": null
},
     { "$set": { "comments.$.nickname": "$nickname" } });
```

This is just an example to represent my problem.

I would not like to hear about re-structuring and optimizing the fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (**v4.2**):

```
db.users.updateMany(
    {"comments.nickname":null},
    [
        {"$set": {"comments.nickname": "$nickname"}}
    ]
)
```

**Note:** It will override if any `comments.nickname` already exists

---

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "comments.nickname": null
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      comments: {
        $map: {
          input: "$comments",
          in: {
            id: "$$this.id",
            nickname: {
              $cond: [
                "$$this.nickname",
                "$$this.nickname",
                "$nickname"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $out: "users"
  }
])
```

**Note:** It will keep already existing values